# How to make jQuery consume a secured service?

Tags: jquery, x509certificate, webservice-client

i want to consume a web service which has certificate based security. is it possible to use the browser certificate (x509) store to consume such a service

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no explicit hooks in any of the generally available browser JavaScript environments to interact with the browser certificate store. You can probably do something using a Firefox plugin via Mozilla's APIs but otherwise you're probably not going to have a ton of luck on that front.